# deployment path in Tom EE plume

Tags: java, web, tomcat, apache-tomee

Why in my java ee application, Tomcat Plume is deployed on the path localhost:8080 only when the output directory for the artifact is specified: C:\Users\freed\IdeaProjects\demo4\out\artifacts\ROOT or C:\Users\freed\IdeaProjects\demo4\target\ROOT and if I specify the output directory C:\Users\freed\IdeaProjects\demo4\out\artifacts\demo or C:\Users\freed\IdeaProjects\demo4\target\demo then it will unfold along the path localhost:8080/demo

at the same time, if I use a regular tomcat (not plume) and specify the output directory C:\Users\freed\IdeaProjects\demo4\out\artifacts\demo or C:\Users\freed\IdeaProjects\demo4\target\demo then tomcat will deploy the application to the path localhost:8080

why is there such a difference between a regular tomcat and a tomcat plume?